# Can I use "earn" in this way in this sentence? "Working earns one more freedom"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request

In Merriam webster I see such a use of "earn" in the meaning of 
"[b :  to make worthy of or obtain for](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/earn) "

But my friend insists that it does not sound well because whatever is used in dictionary does not have to be common usage of that meaning of the word.

She thinks everybody knew that but I thought because dictionary are also open to revision and updates, if I see a word's use in a dictionary, particularly online ones which can be dynamically and frequently updated, it means it is in common use. Am I wrong? what is the truth of online dictionaries, do they contain only common use or everything which then my friend is right about.?

So my sentence is correct and used in common or not?
If not, how can I say it that sounds more natural?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're both right.

First of all, the sentence "Working earns one more freedom." is **perfectly fine**.  Nothing about it is unusual or in bad style.

Second, your friend has a point that bears keeping in mind.  Everything in dictionaries is "correct", but not everything is fashionable or common.  Sometimes dictionaries list meanings of words which are valid, but only commonly used in certain idioms.  Some dictionaries are better than others about explicating these usages, or indicating when a definition is informal, archaic, or otherwise not typical.

It sounds like your friend has formed the impression that using "earns" this way is not conventional or not in good style.  This is somewhat incorrect.  It's very slightly unconventional in that there's this unfortunate tendency among English speakers/writers to use the verb "is" where a more descriptive verb might go, and then stick the informative verb somewhere else in the sentence.  A more common way of expressing the same sentiment might be, "Working is how one earns more freedom."  But I don't mean to say this longer sentence is in a better style.  "Working earns one more freedom" has more concision and clarity, while losing no correctness. As such it might be considered in *better* style than is typical.